# Digital Signatures

Tags: digital-signature, rsa

In RSA signatures, Alice signs the message using her private key, and Bob verifies the message using Alice's public key.

If an attacker has the signed encrypted message, then can they also verify the message using Alice's public key? If yes, is that of any use for the attacker?

Comment: I don't think you have worked out how this would be an attack. The "attacker" can get the encrypted message and public key normally. How is "verifying" an attack? Is the message also signed? If so, how was it signed? Can you expand this out? As written, I'm not sure that this is a security question.

Comment: This is exactly my question. I asked if having the public key, the encrypted message (and then verifying the message), would be of any use for the attacker. Anyway @mentallurg answered me. Verifying the message by an attacker does not mean anything really

Comment: But it depends on your attack and the details I asked for. An encrypted message is not always signed. And this is your question. You must have had some reason to think that verifying might be an issue.

Comment: Again, this is exactly my question. I am assuming that an attacker has Alice's signed encrypted message. I asked in the question if the ability to verify this message by an attacker is an issue or not. I have not assumed anything.

Comment: You are not getting what I'm saying. mentallurg has the same questions. Thank you providing the one bit of info I asked for. We can't say if being able to verify has benefit until you provide more context and explain what you *are* assuming. What type of attack, for instance? If your question is, instead, "can the ability to verify the signature of an encrypted message be a vulnerability?" then that's too open, because then we need to imagine all the potential ways that it could be a vulnerability.

Comment: OP: Digital signatures use *asymmetric* cryptography.  Anyone can verify a signature on a message using the signer's public key, as you describe in your question.  In situations where this is not desirable, we generally use HMAC's, which use *symmetric* cryptography.  Alice and Bob each have a shared secret key.  Bob uses the key to create an HMAC on the message, then Alice uses the same key to verify the HMAC.  However, nobody else can verify the HMAC, because nobody else knows the secret key.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is **the purpose** of the public key to allow **anyone** to verify the signature. This does not give the attacker any advantage.

Your questions is ambiguous regarding encryption. You don't say that Alice encrypts the message. But you say that the attacker sees the encrypted message.

- If message is not encrypted and signed, anyone can verify the signature, including the attacker.
- If message is first encrypted, then signed, again, anyone can verify the signature, including the attacker. The attacker will know that Alice has signed this message, but will not be able to decrypt the message.
- If message is first signed, then encrypted, then nobody can verify it except of the receiver, Bob. Bob will decrypt it (assuming his public key was used for encryption), then verify the signature. The attacker will not be able to decrypt the message and thus will not be able to verify it.

Here you can read more: [Should we sign-then-encrypt, or encrypt-then-sign?](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/5458/should-we-sign-then-encrypt-or-encrypt-then-sign)